# How to Use an Update Statement in SQLDataAdapter in BP automate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I could not update table using this code, please advice me how to repair:
User that I use got insert grant to table

SQL query

```
UPDATE [UFC].[dbo].[CreateProfile]
SET ATTEMPT = '4'
WHERE SKP = 804401;
```

As suggested i tried to use below code, unfortunately not work either:

```
' Assume success
Success = True
Message = ""

Try
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = moConnection
        cmd.Transaction = moTransaction
        cmd.CommandText = SQL

        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
            adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd //------comment:when use 
        End Using
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = ex.Message

End Try
```

Comment: Help would be much apprciated

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  You said the database user has INSERT permissions, but you are doing an UPDATE. Maybe change the permissions?

Comment: Property "SelectCommand" was not initiated before calling of 'Fill'. Also all permissions include update are set to user

Comment: You're attempting to fill a dataset with the results from your SQL Query, of which there are no results as you're initiating an `UPDATE`; not a `SELECT`. Are you attempting to retrieve the results after you've updated the database, as those are two different transactions.

Comment: Yes, I would like to only update with output, but below code still not work:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307587/how-to-update-a-database-from-a-dataset-object-by-using-visual-c-2005) provides a guide on how to perform an Update using a `SqlDataAdapter`.

1. First, you need to  populate the `dataSet` variable with the schema information of the target table to update and the data currently in said table.  This is done via the `FillSchema` and `Fill` methods respectively.
2. Next, find the row you want to update.  Since you previously loaded the schema, the `table` variable uses the primary key to find the row.  I assumed the column `SKP` is your primary key for this table, and as such, I used the value "804401" from your UPDATE query as the value to use to find the row.
3. After finding the row, you can specify the column you want to update and the value to update it to by doing `dataRow("<ColumnName>") = <value>`.
4. Using a `SqlCommandBuilder` that takes in your `SqlDataAdapter`, .NET will automatically build the SQL statement for updating the table.  Alternatively, you can write your own SQL if you wish.
5. Call the `Update()` method on your `SqlDataAdapter` and pass in the dataset for the table to update and the table name to update.

```
'Assume success
Success = True
Message = ""
Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("UpdateDataSet")

Try
    Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CreateProfile", moConnection) 'Note - I don't recommend selecting everything, but for brevity I did
        adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source, "CreateProfile")
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "CreateProfile")
        Dim table As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("CreateProfile")
        Dim dataRow As DataRow = table.Rows.Find("804401")
        dataRow("Attempt") = "4"
        Dim objCommandBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.Update(dataSet, "CreateProfile")
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Success = False
    Message = ex.Message
End Try
```

Of course I have hard coded values in some spots, to which you'll need to parameterize instead.